# Accessing SVN repo via CruiseControl.NET and Windows Authentication

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, windows-authentication, visualsvn

this is a bit of an ambiguous one as to whether it is for StackOverflow or ServerFault. I figured developers would have as much chance of solving this problem, so I opted for here.

I have two servers:

- SVNServer. This is a Windows 2003 Server box and hosts VisualSVN which is working fine and allows authentication via Windows Authentication.
- CCNETServer. This is a Windows 2008 Server box and hosts CruiseControl.NET.

I'd like to set up a link between them both, so in my Project definition on the CCNETServer, I have the following code:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>svn://appserv1/aspnet/regBook/trunk</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\Website\Registrars\Source</workingDirectory>
  <username>SVNServer\Username</username>
  <password>Password</password>
</sourcecontrol>
```

This however doesn't seem to work, I constantly get build errors with the message "Failing Tasks : Svn: CheckForModifications" - presumably because it is not authenticating against the server. 
When you look a bit deeper it says: "Can't connect to host 'SVNServer': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I'm not able to create a domain account, but I'm able to amend accounts on both machines. How can I get around this, while trying to keep Windows Authentication for my SVN server? Where should I look for more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clue is in the error message: "Can't connect to host 'SVNServer': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."  You're trying to access a port which nothing is litening on.

VisualSVN Server doesn't use svn:// on port 3690 - it uses HTTPS on port 8443 by default.  So try changing your URL to "https://SVNServer:8443/..." instead of svn://SVNServer.

Comment: Ah! This might be a good lead! :P
I spotted a few posts about HTTPS authentication via CC.NET, I'll re-explore that avenue and see what results I get. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With this configuration you need to configure VisuaSVN Server to allow basic authentication AND integrated authentication.

I am not sure if this is the only way to make it work or if it is possible to use NTLM authentication for CC.Net (in that case you would not need to specify user/password).

Comment: I don't think VisualSVN allows mixed mode auth. I had a look and there is nothing obvious in the settings and I found a link on a Google Group (maybe out of date I guess now) that said they didn't support and had no plans to :)

Comment: Ahh, that explains it somewhat. Thanks! :)